# Stacking masked arrays - the mask not preserved

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having trouble preserving array masks while (deep) stacking images/vids.

I have two images (they are actually 3D movies) that are individually masked, but when I stack them the combined image does not preserve the original mask.

Here's the figure of the two images properly masked before joining and after joining them - when the mask is removed:

[image: masked arrays become unmasked after stacking]

Each 2d array mask is generated like this:

`image = np.ma.array(data_load[i], mask=generic_mask_indexes, fill_value = 0, hard_mask = True)`

And the 2 vids are combined like this:

`combined_image = np.ma.dstack((data[0],data[1]))`

I saw this link, but doesn't seem to help: [Numpy: Stacking masked Arrays and calculating min/max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954858/numpy-stacking-masked-arrays-and-calculating-min-max).

I added the image below; I thought it was clear what I wanted, sorry for the confusion. So the masking is lost during the stack and the stacked image reverts to pre-masked version.

[image: Target image stack]

My guess is that I'm not properly - or permanently - masking the original arrays. I still have trouble understanding how to use that function correctly.

Comment: Could you add an example and your expected outcome?

Comment: `ma.dstack` works for small test arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Ok, not sure what that means.  Does it mean that I can't use dstack to stack larger arrays?

Comment: Is it not `hstack` that  you want instead of `dstack`?